# Microsoft Assessment and Planning Toolkit doesn't discover MSSQL on Azure VMs

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I need to run discovery on many instances of SQL Server with 100s of databases running on Azure VMs.
Microsoft Assessment and Planning Toolkit seems a great tool for that and works fine with on-premises VMs,  but doesn't discover MSSQL on Azure VMs. Azure VMs joined to local AD domain, DCs running in same VNet.
I tried AD discovery as well as manual ip range and computer name. It does detect the machines (with unknown host type), but gives empty results in SQL Server discovery - all objects counters (WMI, SQL, Registry) are zero. All ports are open inside VNet.
I can't find any source that explains about such limitation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was in the same situation and I can confirm that the Microsoft Assessment and Planning Toolkit still works as per May 2021.

The problem I had is that the user I was using for the discovery was part of the sysadmin role for some DOMAINS\ but not for all of them.

As result in some DOMAIN\ the MAP toolkit was returning plenty of them. In some DOMAIN\ nothing.

So basically the risk is:

- If the user you are using has maximum privileges in that DOMAIN\ the MAP toolkit will discover everything
- If the user you are using has some privileges in that DOMAIN\ the MAP toolkit will discover something here and there. For example will not have access to SQL Server instance that you cannot access.
- If the user you are using has WMI access but no SQL access in that DOMAIN\ expect the MAP toolkit to enumerate the SQL Server instances but without meaningful information like database size, collation, SQL Server version, etc... (it can vary by the privilege)

But I confirm you that I'm using it to discover and assess a SQL Server estate on Azure VMs.

So discuss this with the AD manager.

I also wrote a post about it: https://www.jeeja.biz/2021/07/08/how-to-discover-sql-server-instances-on-azure-vms/